# jquery show hide loader for the element which clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to show and hide loader image only for the element which has been clicked, on ajax process.

Here is my HTML

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="status-item">
                <!-- element to show/hide -->
                <i id="1" title="" rel="tooltip" class="cursor help fa fa-envelope read" data-original-title="Read"></i>

                <!-- element to show/hide -->
                <span style="display:none" class="loader">
                    <img width="24" height="24" alt="loader" src="http://localhost/atlas-dev/application/modules/admin/assets/img/loader.gif">
                </span>
            </td>
            <td class="status-item">
                <!-- element to click -->
                <i id="2" title="" rel="tooltip" class="cursor help fa fa-envelope unread" data-original-title="Unread"></i>

                <!-- element to show/hide -->
                <span style="display:none" class="loader">
                    <img width="24" height="24" alt="loader" src="http://localhost/atlas-dev/application/modules/admin/assets/img/loader.gif">
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JS code**

```
// when click on read icon
$('.read').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var url = base_url + 'admin/notifications/unseen/' + id;
    $('.loader').show();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        success: function() {
            $('span.loader').hide();
        }
    });
});

// when click on unread icon
$('.unread').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var url = base_url + 'admin/notifications/unseen/' + id;
    $('.loader').show();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        success: function() {
            $('span.loader').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

***I have tried `$(this).next()` but that didn't work and stop even show/hide the loader image***

```
$('.read').click(function() {

    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var url = base_url + 'admin/notifications/unseen/' + id;
    $(this).next('span.loader').show();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        success: function() {
            $(this).next('span.loader').hide();
        }
    });
});

$('.unread').click(function() {

    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var url = base_url + 'admin/notifications/seen/' + id;
    $(this).next('span.loader').show();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        success: function() {
            $(this).next('span.loader').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Any idea how to resolve this when the loader image only shows for the element (icon) been clicked?

Comment: where is .read icon in you post?

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar see `<i id="1" ....`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a different varaible for `this` as it will not work in `success callback` like,

```
var $this=$(this);
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    success: function() {
        $this.next('span.loader').hide();// use $this here not $(this)     
    }
});
```

It can be done by using a simple approach like add a data-type attribute in `<i>` tag like,

**HTML**

```
<i id="1" data-type="seen" data-original-title="Read" ...
......
<i id="2" data-type="unseen" data-original-title="Unread" ...
```

And in **Script** try this,

```
$('.read, .unread').click(function() {    
    var id = this.id,// use this.id simply
        $this=$(this), // take a copy of current jquery object
        type=$this.data('type');// seen/unseen see above html
    var url = base_url + 'admin/notifications/'+type+'/' + id;
    $this.next('span.loader').show();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',url: url,data:{id:id},
        success: function() {
            $this.next('span.loader').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I found one issue with `show()` and `hide()` when I use this than it doesn't work but when I tried `.css("display", "block")` and `display: none` it works for showing but not hiding the loader. Any idea?

Comment: I have absolute position for the span. Positioned right above the icon element.

Comment: `var url = base_url + 'admin/notifications/'+type+'/' + id;` line `type` won't work. Because my controller name is `seen` and `unseen` and if we use `type` than it will convert into `read` and `unread`

Comment: Did you change **html**? As I added a `data-type="seen"` and same for `unseen`

Comment: oh no.. let me try to do that

Comment: I have tried but this is also not updating the database

Comment: return a success or error status from your controller and change loader according to it or show a message after hiding it. you can see in consolle if there is any error message

Comment: I already checked console but there is not error, however it is not updating the db record too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56868/discussion-between-code-lover-and-rohan-kumar).

Comment: Okay now it is working fine. I just combined your code and Tanatos code and also added one variable to fix the url issue.

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
// when click on read icon
$('.read').click(function() {
   var current = $(this);
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
   var url = base_url + 'admin/notifications/unseen/' + id;
   current.parent().find('.loader').show();
   $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: url,
       success: function() {
           current.parent().find('.loader').hide();
       }
   });
});
// when click on unread icon
$('.unread').click(function() {
   var current = $(this);
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
   var url = base_url + 'admin/notifications/unseen/' + id;
   current.parent().find('.loader').show();
   $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: url,
       success: function() {
           current.parent().find('.loader').hide();
       }
   });
});
```

Comment: This is showing and hiding loader fine but than not updating the database at all.

Comment: Okay I found your code is working fine. Just there was an issue with the URL. I have combined your and Rohan's code and issue been fixed